# Dynamically load the charset UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 from Javascript

Tags: javascript, utf-8, meta-tags, iso-8859-1

I tried charset **UTF-8** to display the **ä**, it displayed  some square box.

Also i tried with charset **ISO-8859-1** to display the **ä**, it diplayed as **ä**. (which is correct)

But When combine the above both charset within javascript condition, its not working properly. Refer below code,

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var lang = 'German';
            function f(){           
                if(lang != 'SomeOtherLanguage'){
                   //here code will execute. And page should display square box. Instead of square box, ä is displayed. Which is wrong. I cant able to find reason.
                    metaTag = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>';                
                }
                else
                    metaTag = '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>';                   

                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].innerHTML += metaTag;
            }           
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="f()">
        <h1>Latin letter :  ä </h1> <br />  
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tip: always use `utf-8` and instead of `ä` use the entity equivalent: `&auml;`.
More characters here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: @ojovirtual If you correctly use UTF-8, then why use an HTML entity?! That's pretty darn pointless.

Comment: This seems like a backwards solution: once your JavaScript runs, the HTML has already been interpreted. Why don't you just always use UTF-8 and make sure that the server sends the data correctly?

Comment: *"And page should display square box. Instead of square box, ä is displayed. Which is wrong."* – Wut?! Why would a square box be correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the character set is established by the parser, which needs to parse Javascript in order to generate that meta DOM.

You still can use only one character set and convert the data.

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do will never work.

If the raw bytes of your HTML are not encoded as UTF-8 to begin with, you can't claim UTF-8, in a `<meta>` tag, or an HTTP `Content-Type` header.  You would be lying to the browser/client, and is why you get bad results.

Your code will "work" only when your `<meta>` tag claims ISO-8859-1 (and there is no `Content-Type` header to override that) if your HTML is actually encoded in ISO-8859-1.  In several (but not all) of the ISO-8859-X charsets, including ISO-8859-1, `ä` is encoded as byte `0xE4`, so your code "works" when claiming ISO-8859-1 if byte `0x34` is present in the HTML's raw data.

In UTF-8, `ä` is encoded as bytes `0xC3 0xA4` instead.  If your HTML contains byte `0xE4`, but you claim UTF-8, you get bad results (`0xE4` is not a valid byte in UTF-8).

So, your `<meta>` tag (and HTTP `Content-Type` header) needs to claim a charset that actually matches the real encoding of the HTML's raw bytes.

If your HTTP server is serving a static HTML file, the file is encoded in a specific charset when the HTML is saved to file.  That same charset needs to be specified statically in the `<meta>` tag (and preferably also in the HTTP `Content-Type` header).  If your HTTP server is generating the HTML dynamically, it needs to encode the HTML in a specific charset for transmission, so it needs to specify that same charset in the generated `<meta>` tag (and `Content-Type` header).

In other words, stop trying to lie to the browser/client.  Tell the truth, then you won't run into this problem anymore.